# Is there a function in R, which returns number of significant digits?

Tags: r, significant-digits

Somewhere I found this code

```
signdig = function(x)
{
  length(gregexpr("[[:digit:]]", as.character(x))[[1]])
}
```

But this returns strange numbers, like

```
> L=matrix(c(15,5,9,3.111),nrow=2)
> kappa(L)
[1] 239.5819 
> signdig(kappa(L))
[1] 15
```

Can somebody suggest an algorithm or code to solve it?

Comment: `round(kappa(L))`

Comment: We can use `signif(kappa(L))`

Comment: I think the question is about finding the number of significant digits a number currently has, not formatting it to a certain number of digits?

Comment: @Marius is right. `round(kappa(L))` rounds it. `signif(kappa(L))` rounds it to six digits.

Comment: I am able to solve it to a limited extent (i.e. for decimals) using this:
`
s = function(n)
{
  i=0
      while(n%%10!=0)
      {
          i=i+1
          n=n*10
      }
      return(i)
    }`

Comment: @Harshvardhan you say that the answer for `signdig(kappa(L))`   (15) is strange, but no,  that is correct.  I suspect that you think it is strange because `kappa(L)` showed 239.5819 as the result - 7 digits, right?  No. R just displays 7 digits by default.  Try `options(digits=15)`  THEN try `kappa(L)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interest of simplicity, let's assume that all of the values in `L` are precise to the third decimal place and that `kappa(L)` is also precise to the third decimal place. Let's also assume a convention such that a value has a *precision attribute* (denoted `pa`) equal to its order of magnitude.  Thus, all of the values in `L` have a precision attribute of `-3`.

Then the count of significant figures in `kappa(L)` is

```
sigfig = ceiling(log10(abs(x))) - precision + (log10(abs(x)) %% 1 == 0)
```

as a general function

```
count_sigfig <- function(x, precision){
  ceiling(log10(abs(x))) - precision + log10(abs(x)) %% 1 == 0)
}
```